# How can I simplify an integral which has a specific width?

Tags: integration, functions, summation

I'm beginner in math , but I have a question.
We know this graph's integral :

[integral with dx width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmcnu.gif)

Is : $$\int^b_a f(x) dx$$

But if I want to write this graph's integral :

[Integral with Δx width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEoMA.gif)

I must write: $$\sum\limits^{\frac{b-a}{Δx}}_{i = 1} f(a + (i-1)Δx)Δx$$
But I don't know how can I simplify it to an integral expression or etc (because integrals have formulas to find it but the sum operation doesn't have except few functions).

Comment: The integral in the first image is approximated by a left Riemann sum in the second image using what looks to be $n=24$ rectangles of equal width $\Delta x$. Judging by the plot it's done over an interval starting at the origin, so $a=0$ and $\Delta x=\frac b{24}$. The bottom left vertex of the $i^{\rm th}$ rectangle $(1\le i\le 24)$ has $x$-coordinate $x_i=\frac{(i-1)b}{24}$. Hence the Riemann sum is
$$\sum_if(x_i)\Delta x=\sum_{i=1}^{24}f\left(\frac{(i-1)b}{24}\right)\frac b{24}$$and that's as much as we can do without knowing anything more about $f$. Or are you asking something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, we can factorize the $\Delta x$ out.

However, after that love, there is no general method to simplify it. For example, in queueing theory, we have [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/c_queue) that involves summation  such as

$$\pi_0=\left[ \left( \sum_{k=0}^{c-1}\frac{(c\rho)^k}{k!}+\frac{(c\rho)^c}{c!}\right) \frac{1}{1-\rho}\right]^{-1}$$

These are usually evaluated numerically.

The challenge is not restricted to summations. There are functions where we just leave the quantity in the integral form as well and numerical methods are used.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to solve this question : $$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + ... = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} 2^{-x}$$ and I could proof with some ways this question for example geometry and etc , but I found a formula for this : $$\sum\limits_{i = a}^{b} n^{i}$$. But as I said , I look forward a formula and it seems there's not a formula.